Question Regarding Idenitities of Gentry's Homomorphic Encryption on LWE
In the paper Homomorphic Encryption from Learning with Errors: Conceptually-Simpler, Asymptotically-Faster, Attribute-Based Gentry introduces the following identity $\mathbf{a} \in \mathbb Z^n,\mathbf{b} \in \mathbb Z_q^n$
$$\langle \mathbf{a}, \text{PowersOfTwo}(\mathbf{b})\rangle =\langle \text{BitDecomp}^{-1}(\mathbf{a}), \mathbf{b}\rangle = \langle \text{Flatten}(\mathbf{a}), \text{PowersOfTwo}(\mathbf{b})\rangle$$
The given functions are defined as follows using Brakerski (2012) complementary

Let $l = \lfloor \log_{2} q \rfloor +1$

PowersOfTwo
Let $\mathbf{b} \in \mathbb{Z}_{q}^n$ and $l \in \mathbb{Z}$, then $$\text{PowersOfTwo}(\mathbf{b}):=\Big(\mathbf{b}, 2 \cdot \mathbf{b}, \dots, 2^{l-1}\cdot \mathbf{b}\Big)$$

BitDecomp
For $\mathbf{a} \in \mathbb{Z}^n$ let $\mathbf{w}_{i}\in\{ 0,1 \}^n$ such that $$\mathbf{a}= \sum_{i=0}^{l-1} 2^i \cdot \mathbf{w}_{i} \;\;(\text{mod } q)$$
and outputting the determined coefficients $\mathbf{w}_{i}$ with $0 \leq i \leq l-1$
$$\text{BitDecomp}(\mathbf{a}) := (\mathbf{w}_{0}, \dots, \mathbf{w}_{l-1})$$

Flatten
Let $\mathbf{b} \in \mathbb{Z}^n$, then $$\text{Flatten}(\mathbf{b}):= \text{BitDecomp}\Big(\text{BitDecomp}^{-1}(\mathbf{b})\Big)$$



Using information from this math.stackexchange answer on the extension of the codomain of BitDecomp on $\mathbf w_i \in \mathbb Z^n$, I try to see how these identities hold. So far I got the following
$$\begin{alignat}{2}
\left\langle \mathbf{a}\,,\, \text{PowersOfTwo}(\mathbf{b}) \right\rangle &= \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} a_{i} \cdot 2^{i} b_{i} &&\;\;(\text{mod } q) \\
 &= \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} 2^ia_{i} \cdot b_{i} &&\;\;(\text{mod } q) \\
 &= \left\langle \text{BitDecomp}^{-1}(\mathbf{a})\,,\, \mathbf{b}\right\rangle &&\;\;(\text{mod } q)
\end{alignat}$$
Now somehow the $a_i$ must be reduced by the binary transformation, but I don't see how to justify this mathematically. I would be greatful for a bump into the right direction. More specifically, how to finish this proof to get the second part of the identity?

Shouldn't $a \in \mathbb{Z}^{n \cdot \ell}$ to match the dimensions? And what is $x$ in the BitDecomp description? Could you also give the description of BitDecomp$^{-1}$?

About the $x$ you are right, this is a typo on my side mixing these papers, I will correct. I am not sure about $a \in \mathbb Z^{n \times l}$, because the paper does not state it like that as far as I can tell.

Actually, it must be in $\mathbb{Z}^{n \cdot \ell}$. See page 5 and 6 in Homomorphic Encryption from Learning with Errors: Conceptually-Simpler, Asymptotically-Faster, Attribute-Based paper.

you are right, this makes more sense, since we split $k$ of the components of $a$ each into its $l$ bits, therefore getting a matrix representation of $a$ split into its binary representation.

Assuming that $a \in \mathbb{Z}^{n \cdot \ell}$ and $b \in \mathbb{Z}_q^{n}$ where $a = (a_{1,0}, \dots, a_{1, \ell-1}, \dots, a_{n, 0}, \dots, a_{n, \ell-1})$ and $b = (b_1, \dots, b_n)$. Then using the definitions provided in Gentry's paper,

$\mathsf{Powersof2}(b) = (b_1, 2b_1, \dots, 2^{\ell-1}b_1, \dots, b_n, 2b_n, \dots, 2^{\ell-1}b_n)$
$\mathsf{BitDecomp}(b) = (b_{1,0}, \dots, b_{1, \ell - 1}, \dots, b_{n,0}, \dots, b_{n,\ell-1})$ where $b_{i,j}$ is the $j$-th bit in $b_i$'s binary representation.
$\mathsf{BitDecomp}^{-1}(a) = (\sum 2^j \cdot a_{1,j}, \dots, \sum 2^{j} a_{n, j})$.
$\mathsf{Flatten}(a) = \mathsf{BitDecomp}(\mathsf{BitDecomp}^{-1}(a) \bmod{q}) \in \{0,1\}^{n \cdot \ell}$.

An interesting point to note is that $\mathsf{Flatten}$ gives a vector with entries either 0 or 1. Another interesting point is $<\mathsf{BitDecomp}(c), \mathsf{Powersof2}(b)> = <c,b> \bmod{q}$ where $c \in \mathbb{Z}_q^n$. This immediately gives us
$$
\begin{align*}
<\mathsf{BitDecomp^{-1}}(a),  b> &= <\mathsf{BitDecomp^{-1}}(a) \bmod{q},  b> \bmod{q}\\
&=<\mathsf{BitDecomp} (\mathsf{BitDecomp^{-1}}(a) \bmod{q}), \mathsf{Powersof2}(b)> \bmod{q}\\
&= <\mathsf{Flatten}(a), \mathsf{Powersof2}(b) > \bmod{q}
\end{align*} 
$$

There is still one thing missing for me, that is, part of the identity is also $\left\langle \mathbf{a},,, \text{PowersOfTwo}(\mathbf{b}) \right\rangle = \left\langle \text{Flatten}(\mathbf{a}),,,\text{PowersOfTwo}(\mathbf{b}) \right\rangle$ while $\mathbf{a} \neq \text{Flatten}(\mathbf{a})$ if the coefficients of $\mathbf{a}$ are outside of ${ 0,1 }$. This is the interesting part to me, why does the dot product still hold? I can't see it.

We have $<a, \mathsf{Powersof2}(b) >= <\mathsf{BitDecomp^{-1}}(a), b>$. Consider $c = \mathsf{BitDecomp^{-1}}(a)$, and you are done. I believe you are confused because these equalities are true over mod $q$ only.

You are right, this confuses me and I don't see why this holds true. If you could elaborate on this very specific fact, I would be very greatful and give you the "answered" mark, if you can.

The equality does not say that $a = \mathsf{Flatten}(a) \bmod{q}$. It only says that rather than using $a$, which is a vector in $\mathbb{Z}^{n \cdot \ell}$, it suffices to use $\mathsf{Flatten}(a)$, which is just a 0/1 vector. This is by combining the above equations together (i.e., if $x \equiv y \bmod q$ and $y \equiv z \bmod q$, then $x \equiv z \bmod q$). If you could specify your confusion, I can help you.

@ThomasChristopherDavies Another important point to note is when $q$ is prime, if $x\cdot y \equiv z \cdot y \bmod{q}$, then we have $x \equiv z \bmod{q}$ where $x,y,z \in \mathbb{Z}$ provided $y \neq 0 \bmod{q}$. But, this is not true when $x,y,z \in \mathbb{Z}^n$ where $n > 1$ or $q$ is not a prime.
